# Tomcat fails to start and crash randomly

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I need some help. Last week we've migrated to Git (and for now we're using fork as client) and I've started a new workspace into sts. Everything it's working well but I don't know why, completly randomly, tomcat crash, usually after a refresh (refreshed by me or by itself, without any command). I don't have the "build automatically" option actived of course, but still, it's like tomcat refresh itself and crash.

The starting log error is the following (first line, classloaderbase):

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase modified
GRAVE:     Resource '/WEB-INF/classes//it/sabacom/domain/amministrativo/IncassoDettaglioPartitario.class' is missing
lug 15, 2019 12:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAZIONI: Reloading Context with name [/easyplanweb] has started
12:16:54.166 INFO  -  - URL= - org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.() - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Jul 15 11:52:47 CEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lug 15, 2019 12:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'reports'
12:16:54.180 INFO  -  - URL= - org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.() - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'reports-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 15 11:52:48 CEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lug 15, 2019 12:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'magazzino'
12:16:54.182 INFO  -  - URL= - org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.() - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'magazzino-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 15 11:52:48 CEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lug 15, 2019 12:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
12:16:54.184 INFO  -  - URL= - org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.() - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'rest-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 15 11:52:48 CEST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
lug 15, 2019 12:16:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'maps'
```

Does someone has some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess Tomcat may be crashing due to insufficient memory. You can use the [Eclipse Memory](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) [Analysis](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) tool to analyze the heap dump generated. The Eclipse Memory Analyzer is a fast and feature-rich Java heap analyzer that helps you find memory leaks and reduce memory consumption.

Comment: I'll make some test, but it's strange that tomcat started crashing after the git migration.

Comment: Are you compiling your application directly into Tomcat's deployment directories? Assuming you are using auto-deployment (the default), if anything in the web application's `lib` or `WEB-INF/classes` directory changes, then the webapp will reload. If that happens during a (full?) recompile, you may find that Tomcat reloads your application before all the new .class files have been written, and it will stop. If this is what is happening, I recommend staging your compilation target somewhere else, and copying one time when everything is complete.

Comment: It's happening right now after a tomcat's refresh. I'm changing some resources (so no need to restart the tomcat, just refresh it) and it's crashing. Anyway yes, I'm compiling the application directly into Tomcat's deployment directories.